# What's the difference between LEN and <>"" when searching for values?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I initially learned that if I want to see if a cell has any contents to use `if(A1<>"",...`.  But as I receive more and more assistance on SO, it seems most people use `if(LEN(A1),...`  Is there a difference?  Did I learn the wrong information?  Should I ever opt for one over the other or just always use `LEN` from now on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty much the same result. difference is:

- **`LEN(A1)`** - checks if A1 has a length
- **`A1<>""`** - checks if A1 is not equal to "empty"

then there is a length of the formula itself (some prefer to save 1 extra character space):

- **`A1<>""`** has 6 characters compared to **`LEN(A1)`** 7 characters

the superiority of **`LEN`** comes when you need to check for character count like:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=4, TRUE, FALSE)
```

eg. output TRUE only if A1 value has exactly 4 characters